# How did I call different class instance in a class method?

Tags: python, class, instance

I was building a pub-sub NAT breaker using zerorpc and get it done yesterday. Now I am trying to modify my code in order to run publisher as a daemon by using Sander Marechal's [code sample](http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/).

Here is my publisher.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import zerorpc
import os, sys, time
from daemon import Daemon

class publisherd(Daemon):
    def run(self):
        publisher = zerorpc.Publisher()
        publisher.bind("tcp://0.0.0.0:8888")

        # Start RPC Server
        s = LocalForwarder()
        s.bind("tcp://0.0.0.0:4242")
        s.run()

class LocalForwarder(zerorpc.Server):
    def pub(self, domain, testcase_pk, testresult_pk):
        print domain, testcase_pk, testresult_pk
        publisher.add(domain, testcase_pk, testresult_pk)
        print 'Send to dispacher'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    daemon = publisherd('/tmp/publisher.pid')
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        if 'start' == sys.argv[1]:
            daemon.start()
        elif 'stop' == sys.argv[1]:
            daemon.stop()
        elif 'restart' == sys.argv[1]:
            daemon.restart()
        else:
            print "Unknown command"
            sys.exit(2)
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        print "usage: %s start|stop|restart" % sys.argv[0]
        sys.exit(2)
```

And I build a autosender.py for test

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import zerorpc
import os, sys

time = 0
sleep = 10

for i in range(1,10,1):

    ts_dispatcher_name = "KS-1"
    testsuite_id = i
    tr_pk = time

    c = zerorpc.Client()
    c.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:4242")
    c.pub(ts_dispatcher_name, testsuite_id, tr_pk)
    print ts_dispatcher_name, testsuite_id, tr_pk

    time += sleep
    os.system("sleep %s" %sleep)
```

But I get following error msg when testing:

```
File "publisher_d.py", line 21, in pub
publisher.add(domain, testcase_pk, testresult_pk)
NameError: global name 'publisher' is not defined
```

It seems like LocalForwarder can't recongize publisher instance, but I can't figure out why the error is occurring? How can I do to correct this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the publisher instance to your `LocalFowarder` instance, ie:

```
class Publisherd(Daemon):
    def run(self):
        publisher = zerorpc.Publisher()
        publisher.bind("tcp://0.0.0.0:8888")

        # Start RPC Server
        s = LocalForwarder(publisher)
        s.bind("tcp://0.0.0.0:4242")

        s.run()

class LocalForwarder(zerorpc.Server):
    def __init__(self, publisher, *args, **kw):
        super(LocalForwarder, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.publisher = publisher 

    def pub(self, domain, testcase_pk, testresult_pk):
        print domain, testcase_pk, testresult_pk
        self.publisher.add(domain, testcase_pk, testresult_pk)
        print 'Send to dispacher'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply:) Your solution looks great but will it flash out original zerorpc.Server class _init_? Did I need to copy zerorpc source code to here?

Comment: Oh I got it, *args & **kw will do this job.... I'll run the test tommrrow morning & report here. Thanks for your help~:)

Comment: The call to `super(LocalForwarder, self).__init__()` takes care of the correct initialisation of `zerorpc.Server` - I used to generic `*args, **kw` to make sure we can pass any optional params. Note that I have zero (no pun intented) experience with `zerorpc` so I cannot garantee your code will work properly, but at least this will solve your current issue. Just as a side note: error messages should go to `sys.stderr`, not `sys.stdout` (which is the default for `print`, and you may want to have a look at the standard lib's `logging` module too.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you expect publisher to be a global variable. To accomplish that you need to try something like this:

```
my_global = None

def x():
    global my_global
    my_global = 1

def y():
    print(my_global)
```

By default, the publisher var you created is locally scoped to that method – that's the default on assignment. The `global` keyword allows you to set that variable at the global scope level. Functions that only reference the value don't need the `global` keyword.

Comment: why use a global when you can avoid it by passing the variable as argument ?

Comment: I wasn't commenting on his program structure/style – just on why what he was attempting wasn't working.

Comment: It wasn't working because the name `publisher` was not defined in the method - as you do explain - but that doesn't mean the OP "expected" this name to be global, and more over it certainly doesn't imply that using globals is the (only) way to make this object available to `LocalForwarder.pub()`.